# Does Unity's Unet LLAPI compress data?

Tags: unity, networking, unity-networking, unet

Does the NetworkTransport compress and decompress the data sent through the network?

Comment: If it doesn't as implementation, HTTP will on its behalf. The HTTP protocol is meant to optimize transfer speed and bandwidth utilization by applying compression to the request, which mostly consists of characters.